# Using the current path/URL in an if statement for rendering forms in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, if-statement, path, routes

I need to create Sales Opportunities within my app. These belong_to both User and Company. I've configured it all well to allow me to create a new Sales Opportunity either from the User page or from the Company page, but at the moment the New Sales Opportunity page uses the same form regardless of which route I have used to access the page. See below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">

  <%= f.label :opportunity_name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :opportunity_name %>

  <%= f.label :close_date %><br>
  <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker' data-date-format="YY.MM.DD">
  <%= f.text_field :close_date, class: "form-control", data: { date_format: 'YYYY/MM/DD' } %>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <%= f.label :pipeline_status %><br>
    <%= f.select(:pipeline_status, options_for_select(@pipeline_statuses.collect { |r| [r[0].humanize, r[0]] }, selected: @sales_opportunity.pipeline_status), {}) %>

    <%= f.label :sale_value %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :sale_value, :step => 'any' %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
  <%= f.label :company_id %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select :company_id, @user.organization.companies(:company_name), :id, :company_name %>
   <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
   <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This works fine, but for (relatively) obvious reasons, I don't want the user to be able to select a company when they have come in from the new_companies_sales_opportunities path. Instead I want the company field to be locked and contain whatever company name/id that initiated the request. To do this I need to create some kind of if statement that checks the URL and renders different content depending on the route used to get to this page.

My current efforts tried to build a helper method as below;

```
def is_path?(*paths)
    paths.include?(request.path)
end
```

And coupling that with an if statement:

```
<% if is_path?(new_company_sales_opportunity_path) %>
<div> Something other than the standard </div>
```

But this isn't working. Can anyone put me on the right track here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `request.referer` to find the referring url.

Comment: How do you use that? I've just tried <%= if request.referer == new_company_sales_opportunity_path %>
 <div> Something or other </div> and it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry - forget my stupidity here, I'm using '<%=' rather than '<%'